# Initializing typescript variable values via razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, razor

I have a typescript file for an HTML file, with a few global vars:

```
let var1: string;
let var2: string;
```

I the HTML file, I try to fill these values with the following code:

```
<script>
var1 = "test";
var2 = "test2";
</script>
```

The HTML file is a partial view and those are rendered via AJAX after the initial TS file has already been sent along with the original request. (And the variables should be initialized)

This however, initializes no variables. They are somehow undefined when I ask for their values in the console. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Define *"not working"*. Do you see any errors in the console? Open the `js` file with `let var1` code in dev tools and check if it exists.

Comment: @adiga By not working I mean that the variables are undefined in the console (added this to the question as well)

Comment: Please check the transpiled `js` file with `let var1: string;` code. Check if the variables exist. Also, try initializing them to empty strings: `let var1: string = ''`

Comment: @adiga I checked the js within the rendered HTML file. The code does match, but it somehow seems my js in HTML files does not execute anymore at all....

Even a simple 
<script>
var x = "test"
</script>

does not work. When I ask for the value of x in the console it says it is not defined...